# proper way to import django base settings in production settings

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, django-settings

I have seen alot of articles and videos about the best practices when it comes to managing django settings file. And almost of them talks about having a base settings `base_settings.py` and then environment settings, like `development_settings.py`, `production_settings.py` etc.

usually in the dev and prod settings the base setting is imported into it like

```
from project.settings.base import *
```

I have also read that import `*` is a bad practice, so the question is **WHAT IS THE RIGHT WAY TO IMPORT THE SETTINGS WITHOUT MESSING UP THE NAMESPACE**.

One of the warnings I get when running my test with pytest is the namespace warning, which I presume come from the `*` import

see warning below when I run pytest

```
..\..\..\..\Miniconda3\envs\salary\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py:2804
  C:\Users\seven\Miniconda3\envs\salary\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py:2804: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('ruamel')`.
  Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages
    declare_namespace(pkg)

..\..\..\..\Miniconda3\envs\salary\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py:2804
..\..\..\..\Miniconda3\envs\salary\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py:2804
  C:\Users\seven\Miniconda3\envs\salary\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py:2804: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated call to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace('zope')`.
  Implementing implicit namespace packages (as specified in PEP 420) is preferred to `pkg_resources.declare_namespace`. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html#keyword-namespace-packages
    declare_namespace(pkg)

..\..\..\..\Miniconda3\envs\salary\Lib\site-packages\coreapi\codecs\download.py:5
  C:\Users\seven\Miniconda3\envs\salary\Lib\site-packages\coreapi\codecs\download.py:5: DeprecationWarning: 'cgi' is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.13
    import cgi

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
```

I don't exactly know what is raising these warnings but it goes away when I remove the `*` by putting all the settings in one file which I don't want to do.

Comment: I'd recommend `django-environ` for configuration instead of multiple modules.

Comment: Instead of this "from project.settings.base import *" why don't you try this for example "from project.settings.base import INSTALLED_APPS, MIDDLEWARE, etc.
"

Comment: @dostogircse171 I've thought about that, but there are a lot of variables in the base settings so that won't be very nice, plus I have to do it in all the 4 environment settings file, local, dev, staging, testing and prod

Comment: The right way is to avoid multiple modules and stick with single settings.py and use environment variables.